# Xamarin ios - how to check if split view opened in split mode

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uisplitviewcontroller

How can I check if split view opened in split mode (i mean view when master and detail views are shown at the same time) like on ipad or iphone with high-resolution screen in landscape mode? The reason is that I need to navigate to page if detail view is not shown or to refresh data on detail view if it is. Hope you can understand my idea

Comment: You should ask directed question about code you are having trouble with.  Be sure to show your code.

Comment: @tdbeckett, I'd love to, but I have nothing to show because I haven't founded any useful info about this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i used to do that:
`if (this.NavigationController.ChildViewControllers[0].ChildViewControllers.Length == 1)` 
it checks if the number of splitview child controller is equal to 1 (it mean that only master or detail view page presented) where

```
this.NavigationController.ChildViewControllers[0]
```

is the path to splitview controller

Answer (score 1):

MasterDetailPage has an [IsPresented](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.IsPresented/) property that will tell you whether or not the master page is being displayed to the user.

Comment: Is it working with ios? I cant find the way how to make it work

Comment: Yes.  If I check it in an iPad app it changes from True to False as I rotate and the master is hidden.

Comment: can you please write this part of code, I cant find the way to access this property from Master View (which is tab view controller) class

Comment: You will need to pass a reference to your MasterDetail instance into your  page.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right because I`m using UISplitViewController instead of MasterDetailPage. Does UISplitViewController also contains this property?